# PHP Cookie page counter for each User

Tags: php, cookies

I'm implementing a cookie counter for my website.  I set the cookie to count the number of visit every time the user log in, and display it somewhere on the website.  here is the code for setting the cookie:

```
$login = login($username, $password);
    if ($login === false) {
                    header('location:login.php');
        $errors[] = 'The username/password combination is incorrect';
    } else {                    
                    if (!isset($_COOKIE['counter']))
                            {  
                                $cookie = 1;
                                setcookie("counter", $cookie);
                            }
                     else
                            {
                                 $cookie = ++$_COOKIE['counter'];
                                 setcookie("counter", $cookie);
                             }
                    setcookie("user",$login,time()+24*3600);
                    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;  
                    header('Location:Index.php');                        
    exit();
```

As you can see I have 2 cookies.  It works fine, but when I try to log in with another user account, the counter keeps counting the number of visit.  What I want is actually to display the number of visit for each user account.  Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Do you want to keep the amount of active users in the cookie?

Comment: put the counter in `$_SESSION`?

Comment: How often will a user have multiple accounts that they need to log into, and is the counter only local for that user? ie you as the admin do/don't care about this counter?

Comment: cookies are per-browser, and have no awareness of how a user logs into your site. you'd need to differential user A's cookies in the browser from user B's.

Answer (score 0):

Give the cookie a unique name that represents the logged in user ID.

eg if `$_SESSION['user_id']` contains the user id, you could do...

```
setcookie("counter_".$_SESSION['user_id'], $cookie);
```